# Compile Swift script with static Swift core library

Tags: linux, swift, compilation

I would like to execute a compiled Swift script on a computer which doesn't have Swift installed. But it seems by default the Swift Compiler uses dynamically linked libraries.
Is it possible to include these libraries statically?

Steps to reproduce using Docker:

```
user@host:~# docker run -it swiftdocker/swift
root@16974ad4edb1:/# swift --version
Swift version 3.0-dev (LLVM dffa09ffd8, Clang 9f0d189820, Swift 1c720b8f84)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
root@16974ad4edb1:/# echo 'print("Hello, world")' > helloworld.swift
root@16974ad4edb1:/# swiftc helloworld.swift
root@16974ad4edb1:/# ./helloworld
Hello, world
root@16974ad4edb1:/# exit
exit
user@host:~# docker cp 16974ad4edb1:/helloworld .
user@host:~# file helloworld
helloworld: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=c4d42f6185b3d53ecf2dfb0c386263c17cb34675, not stripped
user@host:~# ./helloworld
./helloworld: error while loading shared libraries: libswiftCore.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The argument `-static-stdlib` must be used:

```
swiftc -static-stdlib helloworld.swift
```

For `swift build`, pass it to `-Xswiftc`:

```
swift build -Xswiftc -static-stdlib
```

If you get an ICU dependency error, install it:

```
apt-get install libicu-dev
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this flag is [only available from DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-05-09-a](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/d7f4d4c12beb0159dc7c537bbe846aa9e743900c), i.e. not in earlier 3.0 previews or 2.x RELEASE.

Comment: Like @sas already mentioned, this is not working in the swift 2.3 toolchain :(

Comment: `-static-stdlib` gives an error: `ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift_static/macosx'`. Maybe Swift 5 removed `swift_static`?

Comment: this is the bug to track https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-648